# Formatting a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, format

I'm going through `sprintf()` and other string formatting functions, but I have been unable to find an exact solution for stripping certain types of characters from a string. I wrote a function for this purpose (which seems quite nasty and not at all worth sharing here) but I am sure there is a easier way for what I am looking for.

```
$var = "abc244$%!";
```

now I want to format it this way:

```
$alpha = some_function($var); // alphabets only
$num = some_function($var); // numbers only
$alpha2 = some_function($var); // alphabets and special characters, no numbers.
```

Comment: Please share what you've already tried for those functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To strip everything except numbers, use this:

```
$allnums=preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$var);
```

For all letters:

```
$letters=preg_replace('/\PL/u', "", $var);
```

For special chars:

```
$specialchars=preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $var);
```

Comment: you have used single quotes instead of double for $letters, why?

Comment: @Mfaspk Just a typo, doesn't really matter

Comment: where can I learn more about regular expressions?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: unfortunately using these still lets non-english characters to parse along with alphabets. I am talking about those weird characters from charactermap :) so I had to go with my own function instead.